# Is aggregating images using Twitter's API legal according to the terms & conditions?

Tags: images, legal, twitter, api

Is one able to legally use the Twitter API to search for a given tag, pull down images associated with that tag and then re-post them within a gallery of their own on their own domain?

Assume that original links to the person who made the Tweet exist. For example

> Image created by @bobby

So it's not stealing the image and making it your own. You're just *aggregating* them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this issue is more of a copyright issue than a twitter issue. If you don't have one's permission to use their images and if you are doing it in an automated way and on a large scale, it would be considered as content scrapping by search engines. Yes it would be aggregation, but aggregation of stuff you don't own and don't have the right to use.

I know someone who had developed a news aggregation application using information available on web sites. He did receive letters from unhappy lawyers...

Comment: OK Thanks. That does make sense. I guess I will need to get users to sign up and give their permission before I start obtaining their images.